# Buffer not found in Node.JS browser code

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I want to use a node.js function on the browser with `browserify`. In my code, there is a line as follows:

```
var x = new Buffer('abc..', 'hex')
```

However, this causes an error `ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`. I tried to install `[buffer-browserify][1]` and include it like this:

```
var Buffer = require('buffer');
```

but now I get the error `Error: Cannot find module 'buffer'`..

so -how- can I use the `Buffer` class in browser javascript?

Thanks for any help,

### Update:

In order to build it with `browserify`, I created an `input.js` file as follows:

```
var Buffer = require('buffer');
console.log(Buffer);
```

and I tried to build it with `browserify input.js -o output.js` and I included `output.js` in my browser code, it prints the `Buffer` variable. However, I still get the same error (`ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`) when I try to use it.

Comment: I think I need to somehow use the browserify command and include that file in a <script> tag. But I would appreciate an example on how to do that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is understandably confusing, but here's how to make it work, with some explanatory bullets.

**1)** Create your source javascript file

```
// app.js file
var privateKey = new Buffer('abcdef00', 'hex')
console.log(privateKey.toString('hex'))
```

- Not you do **not** need a `require('Buffer')` call here. Browserify will make some of the node.js core globals available automatically. Since `Buffer` is a global in npm (meaning you don't have to call `require` to use it), you can just use it directly.
- This will print the key to the console

**2)** Browserify it from the command line

```
npm install --save browserify
$(npm bin)/browserify app.js > app-browser.js
```

**3)** Reference `app-browser.js`  from an HTML file

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Browserify buffer</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Browserify Buffer</h1>
<script src="app-browser.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works! And thanks for the clarification. So I need to do whatever I need inside the input code, and just include the output. But I actually want to get the private key and do the rest on the browser, just send the final output to the server. Can I do it in this scheme? i.e. can I ensure that the private key is never sent to the server? For this, I guess I need to define a function inside `app.js` and call it from `app-browser.js`. Then I can make sure the data remains on the browser, right?

Comment: Might be best as a separate question, but yes, you can get the hex string for the private key via other means in the browser. Meaning don't just include it as a string literal in the source code, ask for it via an HTML input element, for example. Then you can get the value, use it to construct a buffer, and do what you need without the server ever knowing the private key.

Comment: Also there's no calling functions between the 2 files. They are the same code, just prepared to run in node (`app.js`) or the browser (`app-browser.js`). The can't reference each other. They are 2 variants of the same program.

Comment: Great! It sounds like what I need. In my final comment, I meant to call a function defined inside the "bundle" from the browser code. Maybe inside another <script> tag after I include it. Yes, I will make a separate question about this. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you install it ?

npm install buffer

var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer

Comment: Buffer is part of node, what is there to install? https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: Yes, it's installed but it's not working on the browser side. Not with the `.Buffer` either..

Comment: It's not node.js used on your webapp project :) you need to install it. Browserify allow you only to use the syntax require and simply the way to develop.

Comment: Humm how is your browserify done ? U have a gulp or grunt file ?

Comment: Could you require an another external node_module ? If you can ok it's weird otherwise is a problem about how you make your browserify

Comment: Yes, I used other browserify modules (although they are pre-built)